# ReSharepr wrong with 'Heurictically unreachable code' with simple nullable condition

Tags: c#, resharper, code-analysis, nullable

Is anything worng with using inversed nullable comparison condition in order to avoid extra branch for null?

With following C# code:

```
public static decimal? Max(IEnumerable<decimal> values)
{
    decimal? maxValue = null;

    foreach (decimal currentValue in values)
    {
        if (!(maxValue >= currentValue))
        {
            maxValue = currentValue;
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

I get warnings about condition allways false and heuristically unreachable code:

[image: ReSharper warnings]

Code works as expected:

```
//returns 11            
Console.WriteLine(Max(new[] {5m, 0m, 11m, 2m}));    
//returns null
Console.WriteLine(Max(new decimal[] {}));
```

Is this a known ReSharper bug?

Comment: [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) take a look yourself.

Comment: In current version of Resharper (2017.2.2) your code produces no warnings, so if it was bug - it has been fixed.

Comment: Evk is correct. Just tested it.

Comment: I third @Evk - I get no warnings with R# 2017.2.2

Comment: Thanks for the comments - It really looks to be case just with R# 2016.3.2 ... Time to upgrade :)